# Panda dataframe percentage clustering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example I have this data frame

```
  count
A 20
B 20
C 15
D 10
E 10
F  8 
G  7
H  5
I  5
```

and if I want to cut it into several group (biggest 75%, 15%, and last 10%) it would be

```
    count   Class
A     20     Top1       
B     20     Top1
C     15     Top1
D     10     Top1
E     10     Top1
F      8     Top2 
G      7     Top2
H      5     Top3
I      5     Top3
```

How do I achieve that ? I know there is a pd.cut but in `pd.cut[target]` it cuts the information about the count (Only produces A,B,C,etc ).

Thanks

Comment: How can 5 be in both Top2 and Top3?

Comment: How are the values for the top 10% and 15% defined exactly? I think the dataset is too small to tell the difference (both are 5?). Please clarify the definition. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: so if the target is 75, 15, 10. then I assume it will work if you get 15% then stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you can use [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df['Class'] = pd.qcut(df['count'], q=[0, 0.1, 0.15, 1],
                      labels=['Top3', 'Top2', 'Top1'])
```

Output (note the slightly different example):

```
   count Class
A     20  Top1
B     20  Top1
C     15  Top1
D     10  Top1
E     10  Top1
F      8  Top1
G      7  Top1
H      5  Top2
I      1  Top3 # this value was changed to ensure having 3 bins
```

But `qcut` is quite sensitive to empty bins and this won't work in your current case. What you can do is define the labels dynamically:

```
s = pd.qcut(df['count'], q=[0, 0.1, 0.15, 1], duplicates='drop')
df['Class'] = s.cat.codes.rsub(len(s.cat.categories)).astype(str).radd('Top')

# for debugging
df['qcut'] = s
df['rank'] = df['count'].rank(pct=True) # not exactly the same computation
```

Output:

```
   count Class          qcut      rank
A     20  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.944444
B     20  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.944444
C     15  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.777778
D     10  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.611111
E     10  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.611111
F      8  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.444444
G      7  Top1   (5.4, 20.0]  0.333333
H      5  Top2  (4.999, 5.4]  0.166667
I      5  Top2  (4.999, 5.4]  0.166667
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks.
But, If I compare this to pd.cut with target 75,15,10 then the grouping should be the same right ? I spot difference, does the 'groupping' work in the same way ?

Comment: Not at all, `cut` uses fixed boundaries bins (whether a value is in a given bin is not dependent on the rest of the data), while `qcut` uses quantiles (meaning that the bins can change if you add a few more rows)

Comment: Is that possible to use np.cut to produce as the sample I show ? I d like to cut it with np.cut method

Comment: @beginner you can produce the `rank` as show in my answer, then `cut` those. The values are however a bit different.